# VGA to DVI not being displayed at all

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a desktop computer with a VGA output.

Connected to this I have a male VGA to female DVI converter.

Connected to this I have a DVI cable connected to my monitor.

The monitor is not displaying anything.

If I change VGA/DVI adapter the same thing happens.

If I change to new DVI cable the same thing happens.

Is this setup not tenable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert analog to digital (VGA -> DVI) without an active converter.

DVI->VGA works because the DVI plug generally will output both an Analog and Digital signal.
There is the occasional device that has a DVI plug but only accepts Analog input, if your monitor is one of those then your setup should work.

Otherwise you will need a computer that outputs a digital signal (DVI or HDMI) to use the DVI port on your monitor.

Comment: So why do they sell male VGA to female DVI converters?

Comment: Probably for the occasional device that has a DVI plug but only accepts Analog input. Then you could use a VGA cable to use those devices rather than a DVI cable. Alternatively if the monitor can take analog input through the DVI plug then that's also a possibility, but most of them won't as that's the whole point of the VGA port on the monitor.